# Base64 to split

Tags: java, android, split, base64

there is a data base64 on the website.(its localhost and look like the following,80,000 lines) I want to take data first and  split it. but I couldn't. Is there a way you know with java?

```
...FBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAMbAjMDASIA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....
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? Split it in to what?

Comment: Could you elaborate *I couldn't* a bit? What happened? An `Exception`? Wrong output? No error and no output?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Comment: all data is image list and I should split it first @ then ^. when I split it  base64 code of a few images should come to me .

Comment: So what did you try, and what happened?

Comment: I  tried build the library with retrofit but the data is not json. then I downloaded the text and made it as a file. with  StringBuilder and  InputStream. I can split that way but my boss asked me to get the data online. not as a file but I couldn't do it that way. @ScaryWombat